# Facebook like button doesn't appear

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

My facebook like button doesn't appear in Firefox, Chrome and IE !! 
I tried the 3 code options that **facebook** gives you to generate the button, but nothing!

Here is the code:

```
<html >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2F3eesho.com%2Fmagazine%2Findex.html&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?....
```

change to :

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?...
OR
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?...
```

and it works perfectly...

Might have to do with the way the different browsers guesses the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [official code generator](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) to get a working code.

Comment: but I used it ! that is the one I used , I just took it and place it in the html code .

Answer (score 0):

I tried linting your URL and the linter doesn't like your page:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2F3eesho.com%2Fmagazine%2Findex.html

The linter seems to like it.

I went to the page in FF and chrome, and both worked fine.

Maybe this was a transient problem....are you still seeing issues?