# Facebook like button doesn't apear

Tags: facebook

Hi I am trying to add a facebook like button to a website of mine but nothing seems to apear I've checked about a dozen tutorials and Im doing exactly what is being said there and the facebook button dosent apear.On firefox it shows nothing but on chrome , IE9 , opera and safari I get a this page can not apear error:

This is the link I'm using to generate the code:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/WillKode/228217780608588

And this is a test page i've created:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FWillKode%2F228217780608588&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [facebook like button doesn't appear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054078/facebook-like-button-doesnt-appear)

Comment: aldo it is true that there is a similar post I've already read it and it dosent solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you testing just a local HTML file? It seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jhchen/D8pgg/.

Try to change the iframe src to https://www.facebook.com instead of //www.facebook.com. It should be the latter (the way you already have it) but when testing locally the latter will not work.

Reason is // mean use the protocol of the document which is great security-wise because the iframe will use https://www.facebook.com if you are on an https page and http://www.facebook.com when you are on an http page but if you are just testing locally the protocol is file:// and file://www.facebook.com does not lead anywhere.

Comment: already did that as I have read on a similar post and yes I am testing on a local server